# Which encoding in regex pattern/reading the file does the grep/sed/awk/perl group of tools use by default?

Tags: regex, encoding, sed, awk, grep

Is it possible to switch the encoding for the regex pattern/reading the file or should I decode everything to the common format (kind of ASCII)?

Comment: I would assume it's using the LANG set in your shell where you run the command. I might have misunderstood your question though. :)

Comment: It sounds logically! So do you thing that also a document read to be processed is also read using the same encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33580/30379

Comment: [awk POSIX man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/awk/) describe more about the LANG, LC_* variables and could be of help. Not sure what OS you use though.